# Keep border height the same for all LIs

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with nested ULs. Is there a CSS-only way to have the vertical border stay the height of the tallest set of menu items? Keep in mind, this menu is dynamic so both the width and height can change.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/simply_simpy/Kmyjr/

Comment: which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: I am supporting IE7 and up -- but for this part, IE8 and up is fine. (plus modern browsers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the `float:left` rule and add in a `display:table-cell` rule.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Kmyjr/11/)**.

CSS:

```
#menu-secondary_menu > li {
    border-left: 1px solid #7d7d7d;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 9px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #7d7d7d;
    padding: 0 10px 0;
    margin: 0 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This works great. It doesn't work for IE7, so I am using the star hack to target these two rules: *min-height: 105px; *float: left;